# Different view of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data like

```
A     B
1     ATH
1     FRA
1     PAR
2     ATH
3     PAR
3     FRA
```

and I want to take a report like

```
1  ATH, FRA, PAR
2  ATH
3  PAR, FRA
```

Is that possible with a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to convert multiple rows to comma separated values.

```
SELECT  A
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM @Table1 
         WHERE A = t.A
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') NewBColumn
FROM @Table1 t
GROUP BY A
```